# Making A List Of Images in a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to send some images to a program at once, it will accept them with the format below:

```
"1.jpg" "2.jpg" "3.jpg" ...
```

The spaces between filenames with quotes is necessary, I mean this will be wrong: "1.jpg""2.jpg", space is required.

Now I want to declare an variable named list which stores names of all images in a folder.
for example List="1.jpg" "2.jpg" "3.jpg"

How to do that?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: @ECHO OFF
set m=
for %%a in (.\*.jpg) do (
 set m=%m%"%%~na.jpg" "
)
echo %m%
pause

Comment: but it will store only last file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're after:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set arglist=
for %%i in (*.txt) DO set arglist=!arglist! "%%i"
echo file.exe %arglist:~1% ::This is just for testing
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

The `%arglist:~1%` is just ignoring the first character because it's an unwanted space from the concatenation process